# My buttons wont resize when the window is resized

Tags: c#, wpf

When i resize the window the buttons dont resize with it, everything else like the websites do but not the buttons. i tried using "border" method but it only fixed resizing the content, the background also works fine.

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="980" 
        Background="Transparent" >
   <Border>
      <Grid MinHeight="1" MinWidth="1">
         <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill"  ImageSource="images\tarkov wallpaper.jpg"/>
         </Grid.Background>

         <Button x:Name="fleam" Click="flea_click" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Height="51" Margin="734,52,0,0" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="images\flea.png" Height="51" Width="235" Stretch="Fill" />
         </Button>
         <Button x:Name="maps" Click="map_click" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Height="51" Margin="491,52,0,0" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="images\maps.png" Height="51" Width="245" Stretch="Fill" />
         </Button>
         <Button x:Name="ammo" Click="ammo_click" Background="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Height="51" Margin="246,52,0,0" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="images\ammo.png" Height="51" Width="245" Stretch="Fill" />
         </Button>
         <Button x:Name="armor" Click="armor_click" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Height="51" Margin="1,52,0,0" BorderThickness="0" >
            <Image Source="images\armor.png" Height="51" Width="245" Stretch="Fill" />
         </Button>
         <eo:WebControl x:Name="fleamarket" Margin="10,108,10,0" Visibility="Hidden">
            <eo:WebControl.WebView>
               <eo:WebView Url="https://tarkov-market.com/">
               </eo:WebView>
            </eo:WebControl.WebView>
         </eo:WebControl>
         <eo:WebControl x:Name="map" Margin="10,122,-5,10" Visibility="Hidden">
            <eo:WebControl.WebView>
               <eo:WebView Url="https://mapgenie.io/tarkov">
               </eo:WebView>
            </eo:WebControl.WebView>
         </eo:WebControl>
         <eo:WebControl x:Name="ammon" Margin="10,108,10,10" Visibility="Hidden">
            <eo:WebControl.WebView>
               <eo:WebView Url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_l-gYeSt2MqIw62EdMZt_wefG0yO9L7dTaRM74c2J1w/edit#gid=2023683591" >
               </eo:WebView>
            </eo:WebControl.WebView>
         </eo:WebControl>
         <Image x:Name="armorimg" Source="images/amorcont.jpg" Margin="-18,108,-18,0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ofcourse it doesn't resize. You need to write XAML code with regards to XAML guidelines not Windows Forms. Try to remove all the margins and start with Grid.Column and Grid.Row

Comment: changing the value on grid.column and grid.row doesnt seem to change the position

Comment: that's because you haven't defined ColumnDefinition and RowDefinition in your Grid

Comment: I strongly recommend to learn about different Panels (Containers) in WPF before jumping into XAML code

Comment: Never position wpf controls using large margins. When you deliver your app to a user with different display settings or you resize your window, you will have problems.  There are other articles you could read but i wrote the following after teaching several devs wpf. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32610.wpf-layout-lab.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to define rows and columns for your `Grid`.
Secondly, remove the `Width` and `Height` properties for your controls.
Finally, use `Margin` property to determine the relative size and position of the controls inside the `Grid` cells.
This code will help you:

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" Height="120" Width="120">
    <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Margin="10">Button 1</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">Button 2</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="10">Button 3</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">Button 4</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">Button 5</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">Button 6</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">Button 7</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">Button 8</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10"Button 9</Button>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```